# Flask don't show ajax data

Tags: javascript, ajax, flask

I want to do a flask project that sends an ajax request. And then in the flask code, I make a variable for it and show it on the page with a jinja variable.

**Flask**

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/a",methods=['POST','GET'])
def home():
    a = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        a = request.form['data']
        print(a)
    return render_template('new5.html',p=a)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var place = 'asd'
            $.ajax({
                url: '/a',
                type:'POST',
                data : {'data':place}    
            })
        </script>
        <p>{{p}}</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong because when I `print` the `a` I take 'asd'.

Is there any specific way to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why did you choose Ajax? This is a client-side technology for dynamically sending and loading data without completely reloading and rendering the page. The response from the server is not processed independently after receipt.

Comment: And what I should do?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused about what [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) is. Essentially, it is the idea of using JavaScript to manipulate the contents of a loaded page.

For example, here on StackOverflow, AJAX is used to notify you when an edit has been made to a question -- a little card appears to tell you that something has changed, and you can click on it to refresh that part of the page. Without AJAX, you would have no idea if something has changed, and you'd have to keep refreshing the page, which increases load on the server and on your internet connection.

With AJAX, instead of loading the entire page to see if something has changed, you instead ask the server about very specific things -- for example, "has the page been edited?". This is done using an [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_API) -- a specification for how computer systems can talk to each other.

An API is the layer that connects two sides: the frontend, the program running on the user's computer, and the backend, the program on your server. When talking about web development, you write your frontend in JavaScript, and since you're using Flask, you're writing your backend in Python with Flask.

As an example, I've built a simple timer app. When you load the page, the HTML sent to you by the server contains the current value of the timer, but because it's constantly changing, it needs to be updated. To update it, the JS code regularly asks the server "what time is it now?" and updates the page with the answer. When the button is pressed, it tells the server "reset the time now", and on the next update, the count starts from zero again.

### Python:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

timer_reset_at = time.time()

def get_time():
    """Gets the time since last reset, in seconds"""
    return time.time() - timer_reset_at


@app.route('/api/time', methods=['GET', 'DELETE'])
def time_api():
    """
    If GET, return the time since last reset.
    If DELETE, reset the time.
    """

    if request.method == 'DELETE':
        global timer_reset_at
        timer_reset_at = time.time()
        return jsonify([])
    return jsonify({'time': get_time()})

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", time=get_time())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0', 5000)
```

### HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
    <h1>Timer app!</h1>
    <p>Time since last timer reset: <span id="time" style="color: red;">{{time}}</span></p>
    <button onclick="reset(); return false;">Reset timer!</button>

        <script>
        function reset() {
            $.ajax({
          url: "{{url_for('time_api')}}",
          type: 'DELETE'
        });
        }
            setInterval(function() {
            $.ajax({'url': "{{url_for('time_api')}}", success: function(result){
                $('#time').html(result.time);
        }});
      }, 100);
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

But if @Detlef in the comments is right, and what you really want is to receive some input from the user, do something with it, then display it in some other page, then you don't need AJAX at all. There is a much simpler technology for it, and it's been with us since the very beginning, in the form of [forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form).

You already tried using `request.form` in your example code. That only works if the POST data has been form-encoded, but that happens automatically if you're using a `<form>` element. The code for that will look somewhat different; here's an example app that shows you the comments sent in recently and allows you to send in more.

### Python:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

def get_comments():
    try:
        with open("comments.txt") as file:
            return file.read()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None

def append_comment(new_comment):
    with open("comments.txt", "a") as file:
        print('---', file=file)
        print(new_comment, file=file)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    """
    If GET, return the index page with the comments.
    If POST, insert the comment into the list, then return the page with the comments.
    """
    did_add_comment = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        did_add_comment = True
        append_comment(request.form['comment'])
    return render_template('index.html', comments=get_comments() or "No comments yet, try adding some!", comment_added=did_add_comment)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0', 5000)
```

### HTML:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
      <h1>Comments app!</h1>
      {% if comment_added %}
        <p style="color: red;">Your comment has been added!</p>
      {% endif %}

      <p>Latest comments:</p>
      <pre>{{comments}}</pre>
      <hr>
      <form method="POST">
        <label for="comment">Add your own comment:</label>
        <textarea id="comment" name="comment"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="Add comment!">
      </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think this answer is a great explanation for AJAX. It may be easier for the requester to solve the task by first submitting a form via POST request.

Comment: @Detlef Thanks for the comment, I hadn't thought of that. That's one of the risks you take when you answer under-specified questions. I added an example using normal forms.